# Calvin cycle question

Tags: biochemistry, cell-biology

Why does the 6-carbon molecule produced when Rubisco attaches a Co2 onto RUBP split into 2, 3 carbon molecules? Is it because its unstable or is there another reason?

Comment: Welcome to SE Biology. It is important that new users learn how this site works. First, finish the [Tour]. We know you haven't because you don't have the badge, and it can appear discourteous when posters don't do so. Second read the [Help on asking questions](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) where you will see that you should do research before posting. This includes searching the site to see if the question has already been answered, which yours [has](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/65990/why-the-c6-intermediate-molecule-in-the-calvin-cycle-is-so-unstable).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why the C6 intermediate molecule in the Calvin cycle is so unstable](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/65990/why-the-c6-intermediate-molecule-in-the-calvin-cycle-is-so-unstable)